# How do I convert the following functions in JavaScript to continuation passing style (CPS)?

Tags: javascript, continuation-passing

Suppose I have the following functions:

```
function f(x) { return x + 1; }

function g(x) { return x * 2; }

function h() { return 5; }
```

How could I convert the expression `f(g(h()))` into continuation passing style? I know that `h` is transformed to:

```
function h(ret) { ret(5); }
```

However, I don't know how to convert the expression `f(g(h()))` into CPS.

In addition, what if `f` takes 2 arguments instead of 1? How would that look in CPS?

Furthermore, what if `f` and `g` don't take any arguments at all? How does that look in CPS?

Comment: The semicolons at the end of your function declarations are superfluous.

Comment: It looks like at least 3 of us have no idea what you are asking to do. Do you have some example of something you are trying to emulate?

Comment: @JLRishe look at the answer below ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuation passing style is really simple. For example, suppose you have the following functions which you want to convert to CPS:

```js
function f(x) {
    return x + 1;
}

function g(x) {
    return x * 2;
}

function h() {
    return 3;
}

alert(f(g(h())));
```

Written in CPS:

```js
function f(k) {
    return function (x) {
        return k(x + 1);
    };
}

function g(k) {
    return function (x) {
        return k(x * 2);
    };
}

function h(k) {
    return k(3);
}

h(g(f(alert)));
```

When `f` takes two arguments:

```js
function f(k) {
    return function (x) {
        return function (y) {
            return k(x + y);
        };
    };
}

function g(k) {
    return function (x) {
        return k(x * 2);
    };
}

function h(k) {
    return k(3);
}

h(h(g(f(alert))));
```

In the case `f` and `g` don't take any arguments, they are not functions (in the mathematical sense of a function). Hence, they are just constants:

```js
function f(k) {
    return k(1);
}

function g(k) {
    return k(2);
}

function h(k) {
    return k(3);
}

h(alert);
g(alert);
f(alert);
```

There is no way to compose constants using CPS. Think about it: `f(g(h()))` doesn't really make any sense when `f` and `g` don't take any arguments. It's better to just write `h(), g(), f()`.

Continuation passing style is especially nice when used in conjunction with currying:

```js
var f = curry(function (k, x, y) {
    return k(x + y);
});

var g = curry(function (k, x) {
    return k(x * 2);
});

function h(k) {
    return k(3);
}

h(h(g(f(alert))));

function curry(f, l, a) {
    var len = l;
    var args = a;

    switch (arguments.length) {
    case 1: len = f.length;
    case 2: args = [];
    }

    if (args.length + 1 === len) {
        return function (a) {
            return f.apply(null, args.concat([a]));
        };
    } else {
        return function (a) {
            return curry(f, len, args.concat([a]));
        };
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.